# Logarithm of two dimensional array in Python

Tags: python

I have an array of two dimensional arrays named matrices. Each matrix in there is of dimension `1000 x 1000` and consists of positive values. Now I want to take the log of all values in all the matrices (except for 0).
 How do I do this easily in python?
 I have the following code that does what I want, but knowing Python this can be made more brief:

```
newMatrices = []
for matrix in matrices:
    newMaxtrix = []
    for row in matrix:
        newRow = []
        for value in row:
            if value > 0:
                newRow.append(np.log(value))
            else:
                newRow.append(value)
        newMaxtrix.append(newRow)
    newMatrices.append(newMaxtrix)
```

Comment: "positive values" implies there are no zeroes. Do you mean "non-negative values"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert it into numpy array and use`numpy.log` to calculate the value.

For 0 value, the results will be `-Inf`. After that you can convert it back to list and replace the `-Inf` with 0

Or you can use `where` in numpy

Example:

`res = where(arr!= 0, log2(arr), 0)`

It will ignore all zero elements.

Answer (score 3):

While @Amadan 's answer is certainly correct (and much shorter/elegant), it may not be the most efficient in your case (depends a bit on the input, of course), because `np.where()` will generate an integer index for each matching value. A more efficient approach would be to generate a boolean mask. This has two advantages: (1) it is typically more memory efficient (2) the `[]` operator is typically faster on masks than on integer lists.

To illustrate this, I reimplemented both the `np.where()`-based and the mask-based solution on a toy input (but with the correct sizes).
I have also included a `np.log.at()`-based solution which is also quite inefficient.

```
import numpy as np


def log_matrices_where(matrices):
    return [np.where(matrix > 0, np.log(matrix), 0) for matrix in matrices]


def log_matrices_mask(matrices):
    arr = np.array(matrices, dtype=float)
    mask = arr > 0
    arr[mask] = np.log(arr[mask])
    arr[~mask] = 0  # if the values are always positive this is not needed
    return [x for x in arr]


def log_matrices_at(matrices):
    arr = np.array(matrices, dtype=float)
    np.log.at(arr, arr > 0)
    arr[~(arr > 0)] = 0  # if the values are always positive this is not needed
    return [x for x in arr]


N = 1000
matrices = [
    np.arange((N * N)).reshape((N, N)) - N
    for _ in range(2)]
```

(some sanity check to make sure we are doing the same thing)

```
# check that the result is the same
print(all(np.all(np.isclose(x, y)) for x, y in zip(log_matrices_where(matrices), log_matrices_mask(matrices))))
# True
print(all(np.all(np.isclose(x, y)) for x, y in zip(log_matrices_where(matrices), log_matrices_at(matrices))))
# True
```

And the timings on my machine:

```
%timeit log_matrices_where(matrices)
# 33.8 ms ± 1.13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit log_matrices_mask(matrices)
# 11.9 ms ± 97 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit log_matrices_at(matrices)
# 153 ms ± 831 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

*EDIT: additionally included `np.log.at()` solution and a note on zeroing out the values for which `log` is not defined*

Comment: No need of `arr[~mask] = 0` if we are guaranteed no negative numbers and want to leave zeroes alone.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative using `numpy`:

```
arr = np.ndarray((1000,1000))
np.log.at(arr, np.nonzero(arr))
```

Comment: Nice use of numpy's `at`, again :-) +1

Answer (score 1):

As simple as...

```
import numpy as np
newMatrices = [np.where(matrix != 0, np.log(matrix), 0) for matrix in matrices]
```

No need to worry about rows and columns, numpy takes care of it. No need to explicitly iterate over matrices in a `for` loop when a comprehension is readable enough.

EDIT: I just noticed OP had `log`, not `log2`. Not really important for the shape of the solution (though likely very important to not getting a wrong answer :P )

Comment: This may be quite inefficient, because `np.where()` internally works with integers. A boolean mask approach is typically much faster here, as detailed in my answer.

Comment: Fair enough. I was going more for programmer confort than speed (and for many uses, a difference between 11ms and 33ms is will not be terribly important).

Answer (score 0):

as suugested by @R.yan 
you can try something like this.

```
import numpy as np

newMatrices = []
for matrix in matrices:
    newMaxtrix = []
    for row in matrix:
        newRow = []
        for value in row:
            if value > 0:
                newRow.append(np.log(value))
            else:
                newRow.append(value)
        newMaxtrix.append(newRow)
    newMatrices.append(newMaxtrix)

newArray = np.asarray(newMatrices)
logVal = np.log(newArray)
```